Proof of the "local property" of limits
I'm working with Calculus by Spivak and here's the Problem I'm currently solving:

Suppose there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$ when $0 < |x - a| < \delta$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

I've seen the response in this question but I think I can offer a rather simpler proof. Just wanted to verify if my line of reasoning is correct since it feels too simplistic to be true compared to some of the other proofs I've seen online:
Proof:
Suppose $0 < |x - a| < \delta$. We know that this implies that $f(x) = g(x)$. Therefore, $0 < |x - a| < \delta\implies |f(x) - g(x)| = 0 < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$. By definition of the limit, we can deduce the following:
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = g(x)$$
However, $|f(x) - g(x)| = |g(x) - f(x)|$. Thus, we conclude the following:
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = f(x)$$
Finally, we know that $f(x) = g(x)$. So:
$$\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$
Is this correct?

No, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = g(x)$ does not even make sense (unless $g$ is a  constant).

@geetha290krm makes sense. Thanks

You write $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = g(x)$$ which is a nonsensical statement. The expression on the left side of the equals sign is independent of $x$, while the expression on the right hand side is not.
